# Enterprise Library not to be seen in GAC

Tags: .net

In our app server, I see Microsoft Enterprise Library 5.0 installed. But I dont see any related files in following GAC locations:
%windir%\Microsoft.NET\assembly\
c:\windows\assembly

The dlls are present only in this folder \Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Enterprise Library 5.0\Bin.

The problem is my batch (.NET Framework 4.5.2) keeps on failing on running as it is unable to find an MSEL 5.0 library in GAC. I want MSELs to be in GAC as we have many batch programs that need to be deployed to the server. Please advise how to fix this problem.

Comment: With admin privileges you can simply drag the dll into the GAC to install it.

Comment: @benni_mac_b SHFusion is disabled for the .NET framework V4 and above. You can no longer just drag assemblies into the GAC.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to create an installer that will actually put these assemblies in the GAC. See MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dkkx7f79(v=vs.110).aspx. The next thing to decide is which installer you would like to use. I've used the [Wix Toolset](http://wixtoolset.org/).

Comment: Thank You for your reply. I thought if MSEL installations by default install stuffs into GAC. Isn't that right?

Comment: I don't believe so. The installer is there to put everything on your dev machine so that you can code against it, not for end users to install into the GAC. It's your responsibility to distribute the needed components with your application (in your case, get them to the app server).

Answer (score -1):

Finally, I worked with the internal team and they already had an installer to install them directly into GAC and it worked. Not sure whether it was provided by Microsoft or a custom built. I am still waiting for a reply to this question which I sent it to the infrastructure team.